# Dig output meaning

Tags: dig

I have read several tutorials but none explained what does the number after the query means.

```
youtube.com.        275 IN  A   173.194.38.195
```

For instance, what does 275 mean? Time(ms)?

EDIT([source](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1035.txt)):

> All RRs have the same top level format shown below:

```
                                1  1  1  1  1  1
  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  0  1  2  3  4  5
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|                                               |
/                                               /
/                      NAME                     /
|                                               |
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|                      TYPE                     |
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|                     CLASS                     |
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|                      TTL                      |
|                                               |
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|                   RDLENGTH                    |
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--|
/                     RDATA                     /
/                                               /
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
```

> where:
>
> NAME            an owner name, i.e., the name of the node to which
>   this
>                   resource record pertains.
>
> TYPE            two octets containing one of the RR TYPE codes.
>
> CLASS           two octets containing one of the RR CLASS codes.
>
> TTL             a 32 bit signed integer that specifies the time
>   interval
>                   that the resource record may be cached before the source
>                   of the information should again be consulted.  Zero
>                   values are interpreted to mean that the RR can only be
>                   used for the transaction in progress, and should not be
>                   cached.  For example, SOA records are always distributed
>                   with a zero TTL to prohibit caching.  Zero values can
>                   also be used for extremely volatile data.
>
> RDLENGTH        an unsigned 16 bit integer that specifies the length
>   in
>                   octets of the RDATA field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

275 is the TTL for that record - ie the time to live for the record in seconds.

If you query a simple nameserver (not googles for example, because thats a cluster), you will see that number decreasing each time you query it, until it reaches 0, then it starts again.

Effectively this is how DNS caching works.  When the time reaches 0, a new copy is retrieved from an authorative nameserver.